# How to change directory to a folder name not having alphabet letters?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, wildcard

I' m looking for simple solution in shell to automate the script execution, folder names are different in all hosts, only trick is top folder name is numeric with underscores and hyphen. In order to switch to directory having no alphabets, I' am not able to make a good regex of it. Any guesses (other than extglob or using shell wildcard patterns only), will surely help me.

for example; how to switch to `cd /home/user/123_456-56/` , using the wildcard pattern so that I can avoid switching to `cd /home/user/123_456-56_12XyDf89/`

Thanks! in Advance.

Comment: With `extglob` this is easy.  `cd !(*[!-0-9_]*)`

Comment: Thanks tripleee, I cannot enable `extglob` on production environment. I have got 1000 servers to run this script, will have to take permissions to enable `extglob`.  Is there any other way I can do this, using shell wildcard pattern?

Comment: @simer what prevents you to enable it only for your script ?

Comment: @Tensibai nothing prevents, it is just the process overhead that is to be followed.

Comment: @simer ??? It has to be benched, but I'm pretty sure any workaround to `shopt -s extglob` before your `cd` followed by a `shopt -u extglob` (if really needed) will be ugly, brittle and will bring far more overhead. You're not modifying the system by calling `shopt` in your script, it will only apply to the context of your script AFAIK.

Comment: @Tensibai Oh! I get that now. Thanks much!

Comment: @Tensibai sorry, I did not write it properly. Process head is, enabling anything on servers requires approval from server owner-vendor and other hierarchy.

Comment: @simer out of this. I understand there's restrictions on global system configuration, but I assume you are allowed to modify options for the runtime of your script. (Side note: in my opinion it's a good practice to ensure the options are what you expect in a script when your rely on them)

Comment: @Tensibai yup you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can use the `find`:

```
cd `find -maxdepth 1 -type d -regex '\./[!_0-9]+'`
```

Note that ehe `-regex` has to match the whole file name, including the directory part.

Answer (score 0):

A simple loop is all it takes:

```
numericdir () {
  for f in "$1${1+/}"*/; do
    case ${f#$1/} in *[!-0-9_]*/) continue;;
     *) echo "$f"; break;;
    esac
  done
}

cd "$(numericdir)"
```

You can pass in a directory argument to look for a numeric subdirectory to that directory.

Comment: @Dummy00001 Did you test this? Why do you say it's wrong? The simple glob pattern rejects any file name with a disallowed character anywhere in it; any remaining name has to satisfy the requirement (although per the spec from the OP, we quit after the first match).

Comment: Oh. Sorry. Missed the KISS solution.